# What are the sequels/prequels to X-Wing book series?

Tags: star-wars, suggested-order, x-wing-series

I'm reading the [X-Wing series of Star Wars books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_X-wing_%28book_series%29), and trying to see if I need to cover any other EU material before/between/after those books, to go in correct "mentioned in" order.

**Are there any sequels or prequels of those books (which aren't part of the series)?**

By a "sequel" I mean something that is probably different from usual meaning. Specifically, a book that:

1. Takes place after a book in-universe (but not necessarily right after).
2. Significant references are made to the events of the first book; or a dependency on a backstory detailed in that book.

---

I know that such links DO exist, because Book 7 ("Solo Command") at the very end indicated that "Courtship of Princess Leia" is a direct sequel to it. But I'm not sure if any other books have similar links to the rest of EU.

I also vaguely recall Kyp Durron books (in the Imperial designer of Sun Crusher storyline) possibly referring back to X-Wing events when discussing Wedge Antilles and possibly Corran Horn, but it's been years since I read them so that one's hazy. Another possible hit (in the prequel direction) is the fact that some X-Wing books mentioned Bakura events. Also, some Zahn book covered Baron Fel's clones.

---

NOTES:

- Any EU material is in scope, not only books.
- The granularity of the question is 1 book (e.g. I'm looking for links to specific books within a series, NOT necessarily to a series as a block)
- I'm not interested in transitive material (e.g. a direct sequel of a direct sequel doesn't matter) - my main purpose in asking this question is to establish reading order of books in X-Wing series relative to the rest of EU.
- I'm only interested in *significant* and important dependencies. E.g. some book merely mentioning the fact that yes, Rogue Squadron existed and was led by Antilles (as some NJO books do), or that Corran Horn was an X-Wing pilot, doesn't fall in scope. As a corollary, any answer listing a work as a sequel/prequel should explain specifically which plot details constitute the link.

---

Of special interest is a particular possible prequel: I'd love to know if any EU book covered the pre-X-Wing-series relationship between Wedge Antilles and Baron Fel.

Comment: Also, it's obvious that Episodes 4-6 are prequels as they are clearly referenced many times in the series. Please don't make that an answer in and out of itself. Ditto, X-Wing games.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted you, but frankly any book that chronologically comes before the series is a prequel, and any which comes after is a sequel.  This question seems to be asking for a list of works which include characters from the X-Wing series, or simply a list of all the non-X-Wing-series books.

Comment: While most of the series aren't considered "prequels/sequels", many still deal with the same characters and repercussions of the other series and stories. It's akin to reading a story arc of a comic. While X-Men's Phoenix/Dark Phoenix stories are some 30+ years old, many modern story arcs still heavily affected to varying degrees.

Comment: @Jeff - the question says "Significant references are made to the events of the first book; or a dependency on a backstory detailed in that book". How's that "all books"? I don't care if it includes the same character, only if it includes explicit references to things the character did in the book.

Comment: Don't forget to read the X-Wing comics if you are into the Stackpole books.

Comment: [I, Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/I,_Jedi) is probably an example of what you mean. Corran Horn, arguably the main character of the first four X-Wing books, is the main character of that one. It occurs chronologically afterward and draws on something revealed at the end of *Krytos Trap*.

Comment: @DVK There is actually very little cross-over between the X-Wing games and the Books and/or comics. Stackpol was involved in some form or another with the original X-Wing, but the story of that game follows Keyen Farlander, and X-Wing Alliance follows Ace Azzamen. The First X-Wing is a prequel to A New Hope and X-Wing Alliance is a prequel to Return of the Jedi, neither have any significance to the books and comics. Nor does TIE Fighter, which follows Maarek Steele, and I don't think Fel even makes an appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Baron Fel

You need to read the trade paperbacks, **In the Empires Service** and **Blood and Honor**. Note that the fates of some characters in this storyline are not revealed until the *Hand of Thrawn* duology and that there are (presently) significant portions of the story missing.

Regarding Prequels...

The **Rogue Squadron Comic Book Series** directly prequels the novelization. The series story was outlined by Stackpol, and there are a number of carry-overs plot-wise between the comic book series and the novels (for example, the evolution of Baron Fel as a character, who makes an appearance [avoiding spoilers here] in Iron Fist and the Solo Command). Corran Horn, as well, makes an appearance in the comic book series as a Cor-Sec officer on Corellia. Is it necessary to read any of these to understand what is going on in the books? No it is not, but if you want more details about some of the third party characters (like Nrin or Booster) these comics provide a great deal of background. These comics feature Ysane Isard as a behind-the-scenes villain, and the events of the comic book series are directly resolved in the *Isard's Revenge* novelization.

Regarding Direct Sequels...

The **Darktide** duology of the new Jedi Order series details with Gavin Darklighter leading a new Rogue Squadron that includes Jaina Solo for a time. Mentions of various other characters from the books appear in here. Additionally, the **Enemy Lines** duology, again from the New Jedi Order series directly deals with Rogue Squadron, and resolves where Wrath Squadron ended up at the end of their series. Both of these book series also provide some more back story about Fel and his fate and how it ties in with what's going on in the universe. These are significant appearances, these characters and their actions are the primary focus of these four novels.

Regarding Indirect Sequels...

Additionally, novels by Zahn typically include references to these characters, as the introduction to one of the books or comics (though it escapes me which one) mentions that Stackpol and Zahn have colluded about the characters story and plots for quite some time. The **Hand of Thrawn** duology sheds some more light about Fel, for example.

The rest of the New Jedi Order series features Booster Terrik, Corran Horn, and Mirax Terrik occasionally doing things that contribute to the overall plot (most especially Corran). Most of the old familiar Rogues are accounted for in one way or another (though not all of them by any means).

Beyond the New  Jedi Order series, these characters all make an appearance in the Legacy book series, and beyond that into the Fate of the Jedi series, the children of the characters you know well are used as key plot pieces several times, and their associated parents are all involved in the same stories,

That being said, sadly, there are still holes in the story and pieces that are missing that never get resolved, most having to do with that unrecorded period of history between the end of the comics and the start of the novels. Now that all of this is classified as Legends, it's unlikely those stories will ever get told.

Comment: You're missing I Jedi which was a direct follow up to the Corran Horn story.

Comment: I,Jedi IMO is not a significant dependency. It functions really well as a stand alone novel. Since Corran learns of his Jedi Heritage in the main X- Wing series, the further advancement of it in Isards Revenge is not a real revelation, but the plot point of Sate Pestage and the sudden appearance of Nrin are much more confusing without the story of Mandatory Retirement the comic, as a comparison for what I included and left out. Nor does it deal with Baron Fel or the majority of Rogue Squadron characters.

Answer (score 1):

The main cycle of *X-Wing* novels take place between 6 and 7 ABY. There are no other novels in this time period. The novel immediately preceding the first book, *X-Wing: Rogue Squadron* is *Luke Skywalker and the Shadows of Mindor*. Though this book stars the `ace fighters of Rogue Squadron`, it is apparently the "old" Rogue Squadron, as the central focus of the novel *Rogue Squadron* is the re-creation of the famous squadron.

The Wookieepedia [X-Wing series](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/X-wing_%28novels%29#Development) page notes:

> The X-Wing series was envisioned as "Star Wars meets Top Gun". The first four books by Michael Stackpole are collectively known informally as the Rogue Squadron series, as together they form a self-contained plot involving the members of Rogue Squadron. They relate the events of the New Republic strike to retake the Imperial capital of Coruscant, and the machinations of Ysanne Isard to bring about the New Republic's defeat.

The last novel in the "central" cycle of *X-Wing* novels is *Solo Command*, which chronicles much of the conflict between [Warlord Zsinj](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Warlord_Zsinj) and the New Republic. As you noted, this is continued in *The Courtship of Princess Leia*, where the conflict with Zsinj comes to an end.

Wookieepedia notes that:

> The following three books by Aaron Allston are known informally as the Wraith Squadron series due to their focus on that squadron, and relate the New Republic's campaign against the Imperial warlord Zsinj. The events of this trilogy lead directly into The Courtship of Princess Leia.

The next book is *X-Wing: Isard's Revenge*. It takes place in 9 ABY, actually with some events *during* the events of The Thrawn Trilogy's conclusion, *The Last Command*. It is thus a direct sequel, following the aftermath of the Thrawn Trilogy. As its central focus is [Ysanne Isard](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ysanne_Isard), who came out of hiding in this book, it is also a sequel to an *earlier* X-Wing novel, *The Bacta War*.

> The next three books all serve as standalones. Isard's Revenge overlaps with the end of The Last Command and recounts the conflict between the New Republic and Ciutric Hegemony. Unlike the previous books in the series, it has many connections with the X-wing: Rogue Squadron comic series, and serves as an informal epilogue to some of the plotlines from that series
>
> Starfighters of Adumar is a standalone as well. Unlike the other books, it has very little connection to other canon, and has an entirely self-contained plot. It tells of a New Republic mission to the neutral world of Adumar to negotiate its entry into the New Republic.
>
> Mercy Kill takes place years later and involves both new and old characters. It is a return to Wraith Squadron and the team investigates a corrupt general.